# how to specify port on grails run-war

Tags: deployment, grails

I can do `grails test run-war` and everything works fine, but `grails test -Dserver.port=8099 run-war` gives me this error:

```
Running Grails application..
   [delete] Deleting: C:\nsl\target\tomcat-out.txt
   [delete] Deleting: C:\nsl\target\tomcat-err.txt
     [java] Java Result: 1
java.lang.RuntimeException: tomcat exited prematurely with code '1' (error output: 'Aug     18, 2011 12:44:10 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol init
INFO: Initializing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-localhost%2F127.0.0.1-8099
Aug 18, 2011 12:44:10 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService start
INFO: Starting service Tomcat
Aug 18, 2011 12:44:10 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine start
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/6.0-snapshot
Aug 18, 2011 12:44:10 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig defaultWebConfig
INFO: No default web.xml
Aug 18, 2011 12:44:11 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core is already defined
Aug 18, 2011 12:44:11 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt is already defined
Aug 18, 2011 12:44:11 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://www.springframework.org/tags is already defined
Aug 18, 2011 12:44:12 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
LifecycleException:  service.getName(): "Tomcat";  Protocol handler start failed: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.start(Connector.java:1137)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:530)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:708)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:286)
at org.grails.tomcat.IsolatedTomcat.main(IsolatedTomcat.java:101)
Error loading Tomcat: service.getName(): "Tomcat";  Protocol handler start failed: java.lang.NullPointerException
')
at org.grails.tomcat.TomcatServer.start(TomcatServer.groovy:183)
at grails.web.container.EmbeddableServer$start.call(Unknown Source)
at _GrailsRun_groovy$_run_closure5_closure12.doCall(_GrailsRun_groovy:158)
at _GrailsRun_groovy$_run_closure5_closure12.doCall(_GrailsRun_groovy)
at _GrailsSettings_groovy$_run_closure10.doCall(_GrailsSettings_groovy:280)
at _GrailsSettings_groovy$_run_closure10.call(_GrailsSettings_groovy)
at _GrailsRun_groovy$_run_closure5.doCall(_GrailsRun_groovy:149)
at _GrailsRun_groovy$_run_closure5.call(_GrailsRun_groovy)
at _GrailsRun_groovy.runWar(_GrailsRun_groovy:125)
at _GrailsRun_groovy.this$4$runWar(_GrailsRun_groovy)
at _GrailsRun_groovy$_run_closure3.doCall(_GrailsRun_groovy:73)
at RunWar$_run_closure1.doCall(RunWar:49)
at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure5.doCall(Gant.groovy:381)
at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure7.doCall(Gant.groovy:415)
at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure7.doCall(Gant.groovy)
at gant.Gant.withBuildListeners(Gant.groovy:427)
at gant.Gant.this$2$withBuildListeners(Gant.groovy)
at gant.Gant$this$2$withBuildListeners.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
at gant.Gant.dispatch(Gant.groovy:415)
at gant.Gant.this$2$dispatch(Gant.groovy)
at gant.Gant.invokeMethod(Gant.groovy)
at gant.Gant.executeTargets(Gant.groovy:590)
at gant.Gant.executeTargets(Gant.groovy:589)
Server failed to start: java.lang.RuntimeException: tomcat exited prematurely with code '1' (error output: 'Aug 18, 2011 12:44:10 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol init
INFO: Initializing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-localhost%2F127.0.0.1-8099
Aug 18, 2011 12:44:10 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService start
INFO: Starting service Tomcat
Aug 18, 2011 12:44:10 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine start
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/6.0-snapshot
Aug 18, 2011 12:44:10 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig defaultWebConfig
INFO: No default web.xml
Aug 18, 2011 12:44:11 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core is already defined
Aug 18, 2011 12:44:11 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt is already defined
Aug 18, 2011 12:44:11 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://www.springframework.org/tags is already defined
Aug 18, 2011 12:44:12 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
LifecycleException:  service.getName(): "Tomcat";  Protocol handler start failed: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.start(Connector.java:1137)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:530)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:708)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:286)
at org.grails.tomcat.IsolatedTomcat.main(IsolatedTomcat.java:101)
Error loading Tomcat: service.getName(): "Tomcat";  Protocol handler start failed: java.lang.NullPointerException
')
```

Comment: try grails -Dserver.port=8099 test run-war

Comment: same error when I try grails -Dserver.port=8099 test run-war

Comment: Mikey: I just tried "grails -Dserver.port=9091 test run-war" on one of my v1.3.7 projects and it works without issue. You may want to run "grails clean" and try again. If that doesn't fix it you may have some plugin that is causing issues. I would try removing plugins one at a time (or start with a blank project and add them in one at a time) until you find the offending plugin.

Comment: The order matters - `-D` args have to be before the script name, so Joshua's is the correct one

Comment: grails clean fixed it along with correct order

Comment: should I delete this question?

Answer (score 0):

To change the port on which grails loads you can do one of the following...

**1.** Change the port by launching grails with the following command line entry:

```
grails -Dserver.port=8099 run-app
```

**2.** If you want the application to run on 8099 by default, write the following line in you BuildConfig.groovy file.

```
grails.server.port.http=8099
```